# .NET + TeamCity: Private Accessors Are Not Compiled

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, teamcity

I'm running Team City Pro (v4.0.2 build 8222) for a VS2008 sln file.

Right now I'm facing a problem where autogenerated code for private accessors in a test project not being generated and causes compile errors by not being able to find those (autogenerated) classes.

The build runner is the default sln2008.

Any configuration need to be changed? I checked the VS build log, and it doesn't show any msbuild entry for the autogenerated classes. The DLL for the autogenerated classes are just there.

Note: I am aware that testing private methods are the best way to do unit testing.

Comment: how are these classes autogenerated? a custom step in the msbuild script?

Comment: @mausch: If I know, I wouldn't be asking the question. Like I said, there's no msbuild entry for the autogen classes, and the .accessor file contains nothing related to any build command.

Comment: ok, first of all we need to find that out. What do these classes look like? post a little code snippet.

Comment: @mausch: Have you actually tried adding a private accessor for unit test?

Comment: oh, I'm guessing you're talking about mstest's autogenerated proxies. I think you should clear that up, not everyone uses mstest (I don't)

Comment: @mausch I am starting to think that these classes are generated by VS, because it is usable on NUnit as well.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, TeamCity doesn't use msbuild utility to build solution. Don't you want to [ask TeamCity developers](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/teamcity/index.html)?

Comment: Could you post an example application?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that MSBuild version is 3.5 and MSBuild ToolsVersion is 3.0 or 3.5.
[alt text http://www.deploylx.com/so/tcbuildrunner.jpg](http://www.deploylx.com/so/tcbuildrunner.jpg)

**Running NUnit Tests with MSBuild**

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <NUnitCommandArgs Condition="'$(NUnitCommandArgs)' == ''">$(NUnitCommandArgs) /noshadow /timeout=30000</NUnitCommandArgs>
        <NUnitCommandArgs Condition="'$(TestGroupInclude)' != ''">$(NUnitCommandArgs) /include=@(IncludeTestGroups, ',')</NUnitCommandArgs>
        <NUnitCommandArgs Condition="'$(TestGroupExclude)' != ''">$(NUnitCommandArgs) /exclude=@(ExcludeTestGroups, ',')</NUnitCommandArgs>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <NUnitAddinFiles Include="$(teamcity_dotnet_nunitaddin)-2.5.0.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <NUnitRuntimeFiles Include="$(ToolsPath)\nUnit\nunit.core.dll" />
        <NUnitRuntimeFiles Include="$(ToolsPath)\nUnit\nunit.core.interfaces.dll" />
        <NUnitRuntimeFiles Include="$(ToolsPath)\nUnit\log4net.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="RunUnitTests" >   

        <Message Text="Include=@(IncludeTestGroups), Exclude=@(ExcludeTestGroups)" Importance="High" />

        <MakeDir Directories="$(ToolsPath)\addins" />

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(NUnitAddinFiles)"
              DestinationFolder="$(ToolsPath)\addins"
              />

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(NUnitRuntimeFiles)"
              DestinationFolder="$(TestFolder)" />

        <Exec
            WorkingDirectory="$(ToolsPath)\nUnit\"
            Command="&quot;$(ToolsPath)\nUnit\nunit-console-x86.exe&quot; &quot;%(TestAssemblies.FullPath)&quot; $(NUnitCommandArgs)"
            />

    </Target>
```

Comment: It is currently running "sln2008" runner, and switching to "MSBuild" will remove the option of running NUnit tests.

Comment: We use the MSBuild option and run nUnit tests. Take a look at the code snippet I've added for running nUnit with MSBuild & TC.

Comment: And where do I add this snippet to? The sln file?

Comment: It's only a sample that shows how to call NUnit from an MSBuild script. You can put it in any project that you want. If you're going to be using TC to manage your builds it would be very beneficial to learn a bit of MSBuild.